# How to make IsEnabled inheritable

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance, dependency-properties

Dependency properties can be inherited (see 10th point [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence#dependency-property-setting-precedence-list)), which is a nice feature:

```
<Grid TextBlock.FontSize="100">
... any TextBlock inside will inherit this value
</Grid>
```

To make this possible `TextBlock` [have to use](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/TextBlock.cs,833) `AddOwner()` for an attached property [TextElement.FontSize](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Documents/TextElement.cs,673). Setting either attached property (TextBlock or TextElement) will do.

I want to achieve something like:

```
<Grid local:MyControl.IsEnabled="False">
... somewhere inside MyControl will get disabled
</Grid>
```

And I am not sure how to achieve it, because `IsEnabled` is not attached property (means I can't use above syntax), nor I want to disable [all UIElements](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/UIElement.cs,3609).

What is the right way to do it? Is it to make new attached property and in its callback change `IsEnabled` or something more convenient exists?

Comment: make non-attached DP in MyControl and bind IsEnabled of any child to that property.

Comment: @Ash, as a workaround? But I could simply traverse visual tree to disable `MyControl`. I thought inheritance is a nice alternative. Setting default value somewhere far away on a top level container is much more xaml-friendly and automatic. I am not sure how to achieve it, adding attached property is easy, but at which moment to set `IsEnabled`?

Answer (score 1):

It was easier than I thought, I have to add attached property to `MyControl` with `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits` and the rest is done by WPF.

The `MyControl` should looks like this:

```
public class MyControl : Grid
{
    public static bool GetDisabled(DependencyObject obj) => (bool)obj.GetValue(DisabledProperty);
    public static void SetDisabled(DependencyObject obj, bool value) => obj.SetValue(DisabledProperty, value);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DisabledProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Disabled", typeof(bool), typeof(MyControl),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits,
        (d, e) =>
        {
            if (d is MyControl control)
                control.IsEnabled = !(bool)e.NewValue;
        }));
}
```

The callback is rised multiple time, so I have to check when it's rised on `MyControl` directly and simply set `IsEnabled` there. It works for all scenarios: adding child, changing value on parent, etc.

Usage is exactly like I wanted:

```
<Grid local:MyControl.Disabled="True">
    <local:MyControl/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: can you explain what is the difference / advantage compared to `<Grid><MyControl Disabled="True"/></Grid>`? I don't see any except non-attached DP has less overhead

Comment: @Ash, it's useful if you don't have access to `MyControl` (e.g. it's inside some `UserControl` or datatemplate, etc.). Otherwise I'd set `IsEnabled` directly. Another solution would be to traverse visual tree down to find `Child<MyControl>`, then you don't need to change `MyControl` class,  but then you have to do it everytime when: 1) child is added 2) container property changes, which was cumberstone and the reason I start looking into automatic inheritance, wpf cares about all such cases, allowing easily synchronize attached property value.

Comment: default style, declared in parent Resources, should be applied to nested MyControl elements as well: `<Style TargetType="MyControl"><Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/></Style>`. it is more flexible than inherited DP, since it can have multiple triggers to change IsEnabled as well

Comment: @ASh, haven't thought about default styles, cool idea. I am falling into [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/299295) again and again.

Comment: @ASh, as much as I like your idea, as much it doesn't want to work for me in real project. Took me some time to [figure out why](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58395780/1997232). I can't change `IsEnabled` of `MyControl` which is defined inside `ItemsControl.ItemsPanel` using styles.